# Debian installation freezes

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I am trying install debian(with usb) on my laptop (lenovo B-50). But installation is freezing on this screen.  I tried several times but dont change anything. I am writing this post from my phone. Sorry for bad spelling. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Refer this report : 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794410
It's a quite common bug, idk why they haven't fixed it yet, but this report should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried a lot of things and finally I solved the problem. But i dont know  how i did it :)